# What type of project will help me learn thread programming

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to learn threading and multiprocessing in Python. I don't know what kind of project to take up for this.

I want to be able to deal with all the related objects like Locks, Mutexes, Conditions, Semaphores, etc.

Please suggest a project type that's best for me.

P.S. Along with the project, please suggest any tools to debug / profile / load-test my app so that I can gauge how good my threaded implementations are.

Answer (score 7):

a few ideas:

1. web crawler - have a pool of threads getting work from a dispatcher via a queue, download web pages and return the results somewhere.
2. chat server -  accepting permanent connections from users and dispatching messages from one to another.
3. mp3 file organizer - rebuild a music library's structure from mp3 tag data, and reorganize them in folders. you can have multiple threads working at once.

I'll edit with some more ideas if I think of any.

EDIT: Since python is limited to one CPU per process, no matter how many threads, if you want to parallelize CPU consuming stuff, threading will get you nowhere, use the `multiprocessing` interface instead, it's almost identical to the threading API, but dispatches stuff to sub processes that can use more CPU cores.

Answer (score 0):

I propose you attempt to program a very simple database server. Each client can connect to the server and do create, read, update, delete on a set of entities. Implementation-wise, the server should have one thread for each client all operating a global set of entities, which are protected using locks.

For learning how to use conditional variables, the server should also implement a notify method, which allows a client to be notified when an entity changed.

Good luck!

**NOTE**: Using threads is not the most efficient way to program a simple database server, but I think it is a good project for self-improvement.